# What leading size should I set for 18pt font size?

Tags: fontsize, line-spacing

I use `\fontsize{18pt}{20pt}\selectfont` comand because I want 18pt fontsize. Does rule fontsize+2 always apply? Say for 20pt font leading will be 22, 32 for 30 and so on.

Comment: It's too tight. I wouldn't stay below 24pt for the baselineskip, but it depends also on the font you're using.

Comment: Note that with `10pt` font, the baseline skip is `12pt`, that is, "font size + 20%", not "font size + 2pt". For `11pt`, baseline skip is `13.6pt` (font size + 13%). For `12pt`, its `14.5pt` (font size + 21%).

Comment: Isn't this more of a design than a TeX question: borderline for on/off topic?

Comment: @JosephWright For me it is not offtopic: I am required to use strict font sizes 14, 16 and 18, and they must look exactly like Microsoft Word's one (though now I understand that it is impossible due to other problems). I figured out how to set up fontsize, but I saw that there is second param which should be input by user. In the samples on the internet there is only basic case 10,12. So it wasn't obvious for me.

Comment: @dig Normally 18 x 1.2 they are multipliers = 21.6pt,however this might be too tight anything from 1.2-1.5

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The answer depends on the font: the size of ascenders and descenders.  Fonts with larger ascenders/descenders require larger leading, fonts with smaller ones require smaller one.

For Computer Modern `size12.clo` recommends 22pt leading for 17pt font and 25pt leading for 20pt font, so for 18pt I'd take 23pt leading.  These numbers would probably work for Times as well.  For other fonts you need other adjustments.

However, a fine tuning of leading requires a real expertise in font and typography design, so if you have any specific recommendations for the font you use by the font author, you'd be better off following them.

Update:  I was asked for other point sizes, so here I plotted the LaTeX values as defined in `classes.dtx`:

[image]

I was also asked for the skip/size vs size plot.  Here it is, again for CM:

[image]

And here are data (in points)

```
x_size baselineskip
5 6
6 7
7 8
8 9.5
9 11
10 12
11 13.6
12 14.5
14 18
17 22
20 25
25 30
```

Comment: I agree it depends on the font. But rather the other way. If a font has a small x-height, it will need less not more leading, because the ascenders and descenders appear to add white space. It also depends on line length.

Comment: It depends a little bit on the language, too. German has a lot of capital letters and needs, therefore, a different approach than English.

Comment: @Boris Can you give an advice on leading size for Computer Modern sizes 14 and 16 too?

Comment: @dig Please see update

Comment: @Boris: A plot of "ratio skip/size" vs. "size" would be just marvelous here -- we could infer if and how this ratio changes for different sizes. Do you still have the data?

Comment: Please see update

Comment: Regarding the labels of the x-axes: Should that be "design size" rather than "x size"? ("x size" might be confused with "x height"...)

Comment: Technically you are right

Comment: Do you have any explanation why on earth it is 13.6 instead of 13.5?