# Which latin modern font size should I use in PowerPoint in combination with IguanaTex?

Tags: fontsize, typography, latin-modern, powerpoint, iguanatex

I am a total beginner when it comes to typesetting and I am confused by the following 7 numbers:
There are 2 numbers for normal PowerPoint text:

1. In Microsoft Windows I can install Latin modern fonts in different sizes and they appear as separate fonts in PowerPoint (e.g., LM Roman 10 or LM Roman 12,...).
2. In PowerPoint I can select for each of these fonts a PowerPoint font size (e.g., 73.5).

And there are 5 numbers for IguanaTeX:

3. There is the reset size number (in pts) in the IguanaTex user interface.
4. The font size for the documentclass in the LaTeX code, e.g. `\documentclass[12pt]{article}`.
5. The 1st argument of `\fontsize` in the LaTeX code (size).
6. The 2nd argument of `\fontsize` in the LaTeX code (baseline skip). See
   [What leading size should I set for 18pt font size?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55855/what-leading-size-should-i-set-for-18pt-font-size).
7. I can linearly scale the IguanaTex vector graphic. (This should probably be avoided for a consistent appearance).

What is the meaning of all these numbers and how are they related?

How can I get a consistent appearance when mixing PowerPoint text-boxes and IguanaTex?

Comment: Never used nor looked into IguanaTeX, so this is not complete and only a comment: 1. Glyphs of a font shouldn't have the same shape for different sizes, LM at 7pt has wider shapes and thicker lines (in relation to height and width) than LM at 10pt or 12pt, so you should use the LM variant which is closest to your actual size. 2. PP then does scale your font proportionally to whichever size. 3. no idea. 4. no idea what IguanaTeX does with this. 5. + 6. Size selection in LaTeX works via `\fontsize` taking two arguments, explanation should be easy to find here or elsewhere. 7. no idea.

Comment: Addendum to 1.: This is done to ensure legibility and uniform look with documents using different sizes next to each other (think about super- and subscripts for instance). It would look weird if the stroke widths would differ much between two glyphs which are directly next to each other. Addendum to 1. + 5.: LaTeX picks up the correct sizes (as good as possible) automatically for you (if the font was set up correctly). If a size isn't available you'll get a warning from LaTeX (font size substitution).